# Python 3.7: Detect name of property being accesed from class

Tags: reflection, python-3.7

So I am making a Class Which can dynamically return a property depending on whether or not a property was accessed on it. It also detects the name of the property when accessed by a class. my class code is as follows

```
class ConfigItem(object):
    value: object
    key:str
    default: object
    __name__:str = None
    def __init__(self, default=None):
        self.default: type(default) = default
        self.value = default
        self.key = "default_value"
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if self.key:
            self.value = os.environ.get(self.key,self.default)
        else: 
            self.value = self.default
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.__name__ = name
        self.key = name
```

I want the code to have the following behavior:

when created like this:

```
a_test_key = ConfigItem('default_value')
a_test_key.key == 'a_test_key' #True
```

without having to pass the key into the constructor
and when accessed as so:

```
key_value = a_test_key
```

returns `a_test_key.value`

but when accessed any other way such as:

```
a_test_key.default
a_test_key.key
```

returns the respected values.

I think the solution has to do with the **get**(self, instance, owner) method, but I am unsure how to detect if a property has been accessed from ConfigItem.

Any takers on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're trying to accomplish.  You're implementing a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), but there doesn't seem to be a class that it's a member of.  What are you planning on using this for?

Comment: I am planning on using this in [http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/config/](Flask) to help me with fetching configuration from an environment vairable. I got tired of writing down the keys that were the same name as the variable name, and I wanted to store the environment variable and default value in one place.